# Dynamic programming methodology

Tags: dynamic, time, complexity-theory, knapsack-problem

I was wondering if you might have some insight into a problem, where we consider an optimization problem:

max ∑ from j=1 to n of fj(xj) such that ∑ j=1 to n of xj <=B

xj>=0, integers

where B is a positive integer and fj is real to real

I am trying to formulate a solution using dynamic programming and to figure out the time complexity of this method.

Im a bit confused about the dynamic programming approach, how would you implement it for a function such as f1(x)=sqrt(x) if n=5 and B=10

kind regards

Comment: What are you finding the maximum over?  x[j]?

Comment: Possibly a question for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am finding the maximum of  ∑f(x) where j is from 1 to n

Comment: When you find a maximum, it has to be one out of a set of possibilities.  What set are you choosing from?  The possible values of x?

Comment: Vaughn Cato, yes x is my variable, however I am first trying to figure out a simple proof of how the dynamic programming approach can be used to solve the above optimization problem.     
I later want to implement the approach to find sqrt(x), log(x+1), (x/2) and other functions given the conditions of n=5 and B=10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is to solve

```
max(g(n,s) for s=0 to B)
```

where `s` is `sum(x[i] for i = 1 to j)`

where g can be represented recursively as

```
g(0,s) = 0
g(j,s) = max(g(j-1,s-x[j])) + f[j](x[j]) for x[j]=0 to s)
```

And this can be solved efficiently by calculating `g` as a table:

```
g(0,s) = 0
g(1,s) = max(g(0,s-x1) + f1(x1) for x1=0 to s)
g(2,s) = max(g(1,s-x2) + f2(x2) for x2=0 to s)
etc.
```

Comment: thank you, im sure you are right, stuggeling to comprehend it though.. what are the states and recursive formulation of this? is the time complexity O(nB)?

Comment: After reading into this a bit closer I believe that we are maximizing from a choice of functions, there are n of them, however  there are 5 given afterwards, f1(x)=squrt(x), f2(x)=log(x+1), f3(x)=x(20-x)/25, f4(x)=x/2 and f5(x)=4(1-e^(-x/5)), is the reasoning you provided still correct or do i need to reformulate it?

Comment: @user87545: ok, your original problem was stated as if there was a different f[j] for each x[j], but it seemed like you were trying to find the best f, so I set it up that way.

Comment: @user87545: it is a simple change to the definition of `g`.

Comment: thank you very very much! I think im starting to comprehend the methodology

Comment: @user87545: The time complexity is O(n*B*B) because of the need to loop through each possible sum for each entry in the table.